# Ember.button when clicked update a Ember.TextField

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I am not sure how to go about it, I want to disable the Ember.TextField and use a button to update the number in the Ember.TextField,  each time it is clicked to increase a number starting from 0. The reason is that when in an iPad the up and down buttons on the Ember.TextField is way to small for a person to touch it, so rather disable the Ember.TextField so that the keyboard also does not popup and have a up button and down button instead which will each time it is touched increase or deacres a number displayed in Ember.TextField

here my code:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10') { ?>
    <div class="pull-right">{{view Ember.TextField class="span1 qnty-bulk" valueBinding="item.qnty" type="text" }}</div>
    <button id="increase" {{action "increase"}}>
       Up
    </button>
    <button id="decrease" {{action "decrease"}}>
       Down
    </button>                               
<?php }  ?>
```

item.qnty comes from here:

```
 {{#each item in salesopportunityitemdata.salesopportunityitems}}
```

then in my controller i have:

```
increase:function() {
  var self = this;
   $(#span1 qnty-bulk).value +=1;
},

decrease:function() {

},
```

I am still in the process of learning Ember as I go, did the tutorial already
thanks

Comment: Do they render as you want them with the code you have posted? If yes, then the issue is how to handle the action of clicking the button?

Comment: nope i made a mistake let me correct in OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your action related methods of your controller within an action object inside your controller (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/) and instead of trying to manipulate the DOM, which is not correct in terms of emberjs, try to manipulate your model,  as follows

```
    actions: {
      increase:function() {
/*This will probably not work since you item is probably within a specific datastructure,
but the idea is to use get and set to retrieve your model's values and manipulate them. Then emberjs binding will automagically do the rest*/
        this.get('item').set('qnty',this.get('item').get('qnty')+1);
      },

      decrease:function() {

      }
    }
```

If you provide your ember objects/model that you use to bind the fields i can be more specific with the code, if you require it.

**EDIT**

This is an example of what you try to do,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UjAgUha/1/edit

**HB**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div class="pull-right">{{view Ember.TextField class="span1 qnty-bulk" valueBinding="item.qnty" type="text" disabled=true}}</div>
    <button id="increase" {{action "increase"}}>
       Up
    </button>
    <button id="decrease" {{action "decrease"}}>
       Down
    </button>       
  </script>
```

**JS**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {item:App.Item.create()};
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
      increase:function() {
var item = this.get('model.item');
        item.get('item');        item.set('qnty',item.get('qnty')+1);
      },
      decrease:function() {
var item = this.get('model.item');
        item.get('item');        item.set('qnty',item.get('qnty')-1);
      }
    }
});

App.Item = Ember.Object.extend({
  qnty:0
});
```

Comment: @charlie_cat then if you manipulate your ember objects/model the template will display the changes, without the need to manipulate the DOM. In general you need to separate completely your ember controllers, objects/model from the DOM and your views should work with the template when required. There are some very special cases that you might need to access the DOM from your views when other ui frameworks e.g. jquery-ui,bootstrap manipulate parts of the DOM that need to be accessed somehow, or you may need to fire an event e.g. focus based on ui logic in your view.

Comment: @charlie_cat In order to access the DOM from your views you can use `self.$()` within view code. This will give access to a jquery entity of your view's DOM element. Not for your case, just good to know.

Comment: thanks i will have a look again. if it is not good practice to use the DOM then i wont

Comment: just one last thing, how can i make the view Ember.TextField so that you cannot input anything in there? I changed the type to text, what should it be? thanks

Comment: @charlie_cat updated the answer with a simple example, hope it helps.